# how to show progress bar center of screen

Tags: android, layout

My code show space on top  of listview (see left image). If I remove `android:gravity="center"` then it will show correctly (see right image)

[image]
[image]

But ProgressBar does not display on center of screen, it's displayed on the left of screen.

```
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView 
        android:id="@+id/listCategory2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
        android:divider="@color/background"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:background="@drawable/border9" 
        android:listSelector="@drawable/listview_selector" />

    <ProgressBar 
        android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/txtAlert"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/alert"
        android:textColor="@color/text"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

       </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: see this http://imgur.com/WKRZHAw help me how i will adjust this?  remove space from top of listview but progress bar still show center of screen help me please

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parent layout which you have taken is LinearLayout and the method in your xml android:layout_centerInParent="true"  works for RelativeLayout. You need to change it to android:layout_gravity="center". You can instead change the parent layout to RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `<FrameLayout>`, it really good for you.

And set progressbar (need `match_parent` for `layout_width` and `layout_height`) as :

```
<ProgressBar 
    android:id="@+id/prgLoading"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Inverse"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Hope to help,

Comment: The attribute `android:layout_centerInParent="true"` has no effect in a `FrameLayout` - you probably meant `RelativeLayout`.

Comment: I knew. But FrameLayout can overlay full-screen. So, When set layout_gravity=center for Progress Bar in FrameLayout. It should be center of device.

Comment: Setting width and height to match the parent would make centering useless, would it not? I think that centering is only useful if it is smaller than the parent.

Answer (score 1):

Make it a `RelativeLayout` rather than `LinearLayout`, and for `ListView` add `android:layout_alignParentTop="true"` and for progress bar add `android:layout_centerInParent="true"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/loading_spinner"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        />
```

For Linear layout

Answer (score 0):

Simple way to center it inside a `ConstraintLayout`

```
<androidx.core.widget.ContentLoadingProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/myProgress"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"/>
```